# Python - is it possible to set a variable to an operator?

Tags: python, variables, operation

I'm developing a bunch of functions that have the same basic structure - they take two lists and use a loop to do a particular operation pairwise for the two lists (for example, one will take each element of a list raised to the power represented by the corresponding element in the second list).

Since all of these function differ only by an operator, I was wondering - is it possible to set a variable to an operator? For example, can you do (something similar to):

```
var = +
var2 = 5 var 7       #var2 is now 12
```

I know that specifically doesn't work, but is there anything similar that does work similarly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
>>> op = lambda a, b: a + b
>>> result = op(5, 7)
>>> result
12
```

Comment: @KevinMills, You can use abitrary expression inside the lambda body (`lambda a, b: (a+b)*2`). But as @kindall mentioned, if you do simply adding, `operator.add` is more concise and maybe faster.

Comment: Is this better than simply defining and passing a subfunction?

Comment: @KevinMills, You have to define a function if you have multiple statements to execute. If there's only one expression, there's no difference. You can check it by `import dis; dis.dis(lambda a, b: a + b)`. ; So it's your preference which one you use. See http://ideone.com/AHc6JQ

Answer (score 7):

Yes! You want the `operator` module, which "exposes Python's intrinsic operators as efficient functions."

```
import operator

op = operator.add
var = op(5, 7)
```

As @falsetru points out, a lambda is handy too; the functions in `operator` are going to be a wee bit faster, though:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit("add(5, 7)", "add = lambda x, y: x+y")    # about 0.176 OMM
print timeit("add(5, 7)", "from operator import add")  # about 0.136 OMM
```